# How do I edit running configuration in Flutter/Android Studio?

Tags: flutter

I created an app in Flutter and it was running fine, but I adjusted something and when I tried to debug it on the emulator, a new window popped up which I think was called "Configuration Editor" or something.  I'd no idea what to do with it, but the app wouldn't run without it, so I entered some random data in one of the fields to see what would happen.

Now Android Studio seems to be trying to run the app with this data, and it won't run.  I'm getting the error:

```
Target file "4,6,8" not found.
```

where "4,6,8" is the data I entered.  I assume I need to blank out those fields again, but I don't know how to open the configuration file or whatever it was where I entered the data!

Comment: How are you running the app?

Comment: In Android Studio, I'm hitting the "debug" button to run on an emulator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you messed up the running configuration for the project, setting a file that doesn't exist "4,6,8".

Anyway, if this is the problem, you can configure it again in Android Studio:

[image]

Then set the entry file 'main.dart' of your project. The 'additional arguments' and 'flavor' are optional.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's exactly what I did! That's it fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped when i edit configuration of my app

Answer (score 3):

In my case it occur due to the reason that **pubspec.yaml** is missing that is why main.dart is not running as it did not found flutter sdk and other dependencies present pubspec.yaml file.