# Calling woocommerce API from flutter without embedding consumer key and secret in mobile app

Tags: flutter, react-native, woocommerce, mobile, woocommerce-rest-api

For a mobile app that calls WooCommerce REST API, consumer key and secret are needed.
However it might be a security risk to embed it in the mobile app code. Is there any way to work around this?

Tried to see if there is a way to store the key securely but there doesn't seem to be anyway

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage
Speaks for itself, let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your flutter project create a file `env.json`
Put the content in created file like this:

```
{
 "consumer_key":"<YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY>",
}
```

In your code access your consumer key like this.

```
const String baseUrl = String.fromEnvironment("base_url");
```

This constructor is only guaranteed to work when invoked as const. (Refer documentation for method `String.fromEnvironment`)

Edit your main.dart configurations and put additional run args as:

```
--dart-define-from-file=env.json
```

[How to Edit running configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032130/how-do-i-edit-running-configuration-in-flutter-android-studio)

For building the APK use:

```
flutter build apk --dart-define-from-file=env.json
```

Use same command line argument for appbundle.

This will work in Flutter >=3.7

You can easily refer community for adding this additional command line argument in iOS configurations.

Real question: is it secure?

I developed an application with environment variables and my pen tester was unable to find keys in reverse engineering. Environment variable assigned at runtime so they are not part of your code.

Comment: What about creating consumer_secret for a role that only has customer credentials? I think that might work if only accessing customer featuers

For logged in user, we can get them to use OAuth